# Kill a Long Running User Process in Linux using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a shell script for killing a long running user process(which exceeds certain amount of time).

These are my observations regarding this:

1. The script doesn't kill any daemon process
2. The script needs to identify the list of users and needs to check whether it is a daemon process or not?For that we can check the terminal in which the process depends(In general daemon process doesn't depends any terminal)
3. The Process id and name needs to be gathered automatically through the script.For that first needs to get the Elapsed time of all the process and check with our limit of time,from here we filterout the list of process which are excedding our limit and check with whether it depends with any terminal and under which user the process runs.
4. Before deleting the process we need to get the confirmation whether i can kill the process or not?

This is what I've tried:

```
user = " " " " 
for i in user
  users="user1 user2 user3" 
  for u in $users ; do 
    ps -o etime,pid,comm -u $u | grep "here what i need to grep?" | while read in ; do 
    ET=`echo $in | cut -f1 -d":"` 
    [[ $ET -ge 10 ]]&&{ PID=`echo $in | cut -f2 -d" "` ; kill -HUP $PID ; } 
  done 
done
```

Help me

Comment: Why don't you use limits (`serlimit`  or `ulimit`)?

Comment: ulimit is used to limit the number of process users can run along with available system resources.I dont want to limit the number of process.I just wants to check if the process exceeds certain amount of time,if yes means kill it.This is what i want

Comment: How about `ulimit -t` which sets "the maximum amount of cpu time in seconds"?

Comment: Why do you loop over a single space twice in the outermost loop?  Assuming you fix the syntax error in the assignment (can't have whitespace around equals sign).

Comment: `ulimit` can also be used to limit the address space, and many other things ("data" heap, file descriptors, etc...). Read [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)

Answer (score 3):

This will `kill -HUP` any process that (a) belongs to a user on the specified list, (b) is not attached to a terminal, and (c) is more than 10 minutes old:

```
#!/bin/sh
users=("user1" "user2")
for user in "${users[@]}"
do 
    ps -o etime,euid,pid,tty,comm -u "$user" | while read etime euid pid tty comm
    do 
        [ "$etime" = ELAPSED ] && continue
        [ "$tty" = '?' ] && continue
        do_kill=$(echo "$etime" | awk -F'[-:]' 'NF==3{sub(/^/,"0-")} $1>0 || $2>0 ||$3>=10 {print "Kill"}')
        [ "$do_kill" ] || continue
        kill -HUP "$pid"
    done
done
```

#### How elapsed time is analyzed

`ps` delivers elapsed time in the format days-hh:mm:ss for jobs more than a day old or `hh:mm:ss` for jobs less than a day old.  `awk` is used to interpret this and decide if the job is ten or more minutes old.  That is done with the following command:

```
echo "$etime" | awk -F'[-:]' 'NF==3{sub(/^/,"0-")} $1>0 || $2>0 ||$3>=10 {print "Kill"}'
```

If the job is 10 or more minutes old, `awk` prints `Kill`.  Otherwise, it prints nothing.

Taking each part of the `awk` command in turn:

- `-F'[-:]'`

  This tells `awk` to break fields on either a dash or colon.
- `NF==3{sub(/^/,"0-")}`

  If there are only three fields, then we add the missing day field to the beginning of the line.  This assures that the next command sees a uniform format.
- `$1>0 || $2>0 ||$3>=10 {print "Kill"}`

  If (a) the number of days, `$1`, is greater than zero,  or (b) the number of hours, `$2`, is greater than zero, or (c) the number of minutes is greater than or equal to 10, then print `Kill`.  Otherwise, nothing is printed.

#### Asking for confirmation before killing

The following prompts the user to OK applying `kill -HUP` to the process

```
#!/bin/bash
users=("user1" "user2")
exec 3<&0
for user in "${users[@]}"
do
    ps -o etime,euid,pid,tty,comm -u "$user" | while read etime euid pid tty comm
    do
        [ "$etime" = ELAPSED ] && continue
        [ "$tty" = '?' ] && continue
        do_kill=$(echo "$etime" | awk -F'[-:]' 'NF==3{sub(/^/,"0-")} $1>0 || $2>0 ||$3>=10 {print "Kill"}')
        [ "$do_kill" ] || continue
        echo "$user $etime $euid $pid $tty $comm"
        read -p "OK to kill this process (y/N)? " -u 3 ok
        [[ "${ok,,}" =~ y ]] || continue
        echo "Killing $pid"
        kill -HUP "$pid"
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks john.But why you put condition like this "$euid" -ge 10  I didn't get this?

Comment: @user1507 OK.  Maybe I misinterpreted your intention.  In your question, what was the purpose of the code `[[ $ET -ge 10 ]]`?

Comment: :It means ET-Elapsed time.If the elapsed time for a process is more than 10 minutes means it needs to kill the process.My question is $euid" -ge 10 what it represents?

Comment: @user1507 OK.  That is simple.  The answer is updated to kill jobs 10 or more minutes old.

Comment: This Looks fine.Thank you john.But I have ne doubt on this.Whether it kill daemon process or not?if yes means how to avoid that?

Comment: @user1507 OK.  I added code to skip all processes not attached to a terminal, that is, processes for which `tty` is `?`.

Comment: Thanks john.The expected result came.one more doubt suppose if a user process is act as a daemon process means how can we avoid that also?

Comment: bash is also attached to one terminal in that case if we kill that means the other processes attached with the terminal also collapsed.In that case how can we kill that?

Comment: "${ok,,}" what is the meaning of this john?

Comment: @user1507 **Case  modification**. `${ok,,}` expands to every character in the (above read) variable `ok` converted to lowercase, e. g. `YES` becomes `yes`.